# Can the Lie group $\text{Aff}(1)$ be extended?

Tags: lie-groups, transformation-groups

Translations over  $\mathbb{R}^1$ (ie. $(x\rightarrow x+b)$) form the Lie group $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

If we add the scaling operations over $\mathbb{R}^1$ , we can form the Lie group $\text{Aff}(1)$, which contains transformations of the kind $(x\rightarrow ax+b)$. This extends our previous Lie group, as it contains new transformations.

I was wondering if there can exist an even larger (but still finite-dimensional) Lie group of transformations over $\mathbb{R}^1$, which contains $\text{Aff}(1)$ as a subgroup. I know that the group of difeomorphism over $\mathbb{R}^1$ contains affine transformations as a subgroup, but this is an infinite-dimensional Lie group.

Comment: If instead we act on $\mathbb{R}^1 \cup \infty$ then there is the real Lie group $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of Möbius transformations.